# C# - En que parte de la memoria se almacenan los array

Tags: c#, array, memoria, stack, heap

yo ya tenía conocimientos en programación y actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo C#, pero me ha surgido una duda con los arrays respecto a como los gestiona la memoria.
Normalmente (por lo menos en los lenguajes que conocía) los arrays no se pueden crear en tiempo de ejecución, si no que tienen que estar definidos por constantes y son creados previo al inicio del programa, por lo que son gestionados por la memoria Stack. Pero ahorita mientras aprendía C# me di cuenta de que si puedo definir el tamaño de los arrays utilizando variables, entonces me entra la duda de si estos arrays pasarían a estar en la memoria stack o heap, mi intuición me dice que la heap, pero se me hace raro.

Comment: En C# nada es lo que parece. `int`, `bool`, `float` y otros son alias para los tipos `Int32`, `Boolean`, `Single` que son structs. `string` también es un alias a la clase `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C# existen 2 tipos, los de [referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) y los de [valor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

Los tipos de referencia comprenden a las clases, que van a parar a un heap administrado.

Los tipos de valor contienen sus datos, entonces van al stack. Dentro de esta categoría se encuentran los structs. Puedes deducir esto ya que en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs) dice que no necesitan asignación de memoria del heap.

Un pequeño detalle es que un tipo de valor dentro de una clase como la siguiente se guardará en el heap junto con la instancia de la clase:

```
class A {
    int B;
}
```

En la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-6.0) también puedes discernir que los arrays son en realidad una clase. Así que se guardan en el heap.

Algunos links útiles:

- https://medium.com/c-programming/c-memory-management-part-1-c03741c24e4b
- https://medium.com/@ubale.vikas9/stack-and-heap-memory-2fc2a8229d1b
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: nota: ABSOLUTAMENTE todo es un objeto en c#.. todo hereda de object.. pero todo todo... inclusive las clases que escribe uno...

Comment: Aquí hay una confusión, una variable de un tipo de valor puede ir en el stack o heap, que a su vez, una variable de tipo de referencia puede ir en el  stack o heap, todo dependerá en que ámbito se declara la variable.